# When should I use MPI_Datatype instead of serializing manualy?

Tags: mpi

It's all begun when I needed to MPI_Bcast a 64 bit integer. Since MPI does not know how to handle it I did:

```
template<typename T>
inline int BcastObjects(T* pointer, 
                        int count, 
                        int root, 
                        MPI_Comm comm)
{
    return MPI_Bcast(pointer, 
                     count * sizeof(*pointer), 
                     MPI_BYTE, 
                     root,
                     comm);
}
```

Now I can do:

```
int64_t i = 0;
BcastObjects(&i, 1, root_rank, some_communicator);
```

Then I started to use BcastObjects to send over an array of structures. I wonder if it's OK to do that?

The manuals about MPI_Datatype focus on how to do it, but not on why would I want to do it.

Comment: On 64-bit platforms you can use MPI_LONG_LONG and MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG for 64-bit indegers.

Comment: @Sergey I somehow missed it. Thanks.

Comment: Function manuals document interfaces and semantics, not MPI fundamentals. There is a whole page in the [MPI standard](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/docs.html) (the first one from the "Datatypes" chapter) which explains what you might need derived datatypes for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use [`MPI_INT64_T`](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi22-report/node44.htm)?

You can always mock up your own datatypes with `MPI_Byte` or what have you; the datatype stuff is there so that you don't have to.  And in many cases it's much easier; if you want to send data that has "holes" in it (eg, a slice of a multidimensional array, data in a structure that has gaps), you can map that out fairly straighforwardly with a datatype, whereas you'd have to manually count out byte strings and use something like [`MPI_Pack`](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-11-html/node62.html) otherwise.   And of course describing the data at a higher level is certainly less brittle if something in your data structure changes.

Comment: So the answer is that I need that, when the data structure I am going to send is not continuous?
My second best guess is to use it for your own MPI_Op? Can you define your own MPI_Op and use it say for MPI_Reduce?

Comment: You probably never _need_ it; you never _need_ collectives, but they make for shorter, faster, more robust, clearer code.  You can certainly create your own operator on your own type (see, for instance, this question and answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285442/mpi-get-processor-with-minimum-value/9285552#9285552 ) but even that you *could* do by using mpi_byte and counts; after all, it's all bytes on the wire.  But your code is going to be simpler, shorter, less error-prone, and less brittle if you use MPI data types rather than reinventing them yourself.