# Negative Scaling of MPI_Allgather

Tags: c, runtime, mpi

I am facing a problem as I am programming a parallel molecular dynamics algorithm in C where all the cores compute the smallest collision time and then communicate the collisionpartners via MPI_Allgather to all other cores to see which collision is the earliest.
I have built in a time measure function to see how the different parts of my program are scaling. This shows that for 8 nodes (192 cores) the Allgather takes 2000 seconds for 100k timesteps while it takes 5000 seconds for 20 nodes (480).

I use the Cray compiler on a Cray system with the following flags:

```
    add_definitions(-DNDEBUG)
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-O3 -h c99,pl=./compiler_information,wp")
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-h pl=./compiler_information,wp")
```

and the part of the code looks like this:

```
    MPI_Barrier(cartcomm);

    START(scmcdm_Allgather); // time measure
        MPI_Allgather(v_min_cpartner, 1, mpi_vector5, min_cpartners, 1, mpi_vector5, cartcomm);
    STOP(scmcdm_Allgather); // time measure
```

where mpi_vector5 is a continuous datatype containing 5 doubles:

```
MPI_Type_contiguous(5, MPI_DOUBLE, &mpi_vector5);
```

Is this normal behavior? How do I optimize this?

UPDATE:
Thanks for your comments, I implemented 2 other ways of solving the problem:

1. All cores first send an integer value if they actually have a collision in the given timestep (only a few will) and then only the cores that have a collision communicate it to core 0 which then broadcasts the minimum.

Here the first step is slow where all cores communicate with core 0. Is there any possibility in MPI to skip this step and have a collective communication routine where only part of the core participate in? (namely the ones that have a minimum)

2. Instead of communcating the vector5 I used a double_int pair with the collisiontime and the rank to use the minloc function. The core with the minimum collision time then broadcasts the vector5.

This solution is the fastest so far, but still it scales negatively (1600s on 8 nodes, 3000s on 20 nodes).

Any other idea?

Comment: If you are only interested in the earliest event, you can merge the `MPI_Allgather()` and the loop searching for the earliest event : a [`MPI_Allreduce()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Allreduce.html) using a [customized operation](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node80.html) (finding earliest) can do the trick. See [example](http://scv.bu.edu/~kadin/advanced-MPI/chapter1/chapter1.html).

Comment: @francis has a very good point - one problem here is that the data volumes will necessarily increase linearly with the number of MPI tasks in this case.  There's at least one [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285442/mpi-get-processor-with-minimum-value/9285552#9285552) about custom operations and finding the location of a minimum, and there may be others.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the issue of the original question:

1. Keep your MPI simple. Avoid datatypes if you have something like sending 5 doubles. So if you are sending 5 doubles, say so: `MPI_Allgather(v_min_cpartner, 5, MPI_DOUBLE, min_cpartners, 5, MPI_DOUBLE, cartcomm)`

   The reason for this is that unfortunately the case for user-defined MPI datatypes may not be always optimized.
2. I assume that you are printing when the operation has finished in rank 0. This is a way, but it may give you an incomplete picture. The best way is to time for each rank and then run an `MPI_Allreduce` to find the max value of the time reported by all ranks.

   Collective operations finish in different times on different ranks and MPI implementations change algorithms internally depending on number of ranks, payload, size of the machine allocation etc.  Counting the time on a specific rank makes sense if that rank is on your critical path of an MPMD program; if you are executing and SPMD program you will have to wait for the rank that took the longest in your next collective operation or synchronization point.