# MPI_MINLOC in Fortran

Tags: optimization, fortran, mpi

I would like to find the position and value of the minimum element of 
a very long array in Fortran.

The build-in function MINLOC works well:

```
position = MINLOC(long_array(:), 1)
value = long_array(position)
```

However this is very slow because of the array size. 
I would like to parallelize this using MPI.

To my surprise, it seems MPI_MINLOC can give you the value of minimum and 
also the rank that hold that value but not the position within that rank.

Something like (from [MPI Get Processor with Minimum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285442/mpi-get-processor-with-minimum-value)):

```
local = long_array[slice]
MPI_Allreduce(local, global, 1, MPI_2INT, MPI_MINLOC, MPI_COMM_WORLD)
print*,'Rank ',global[1]
print*,'Value', global[0]
```

where 'slice' is 1/n part of the array with n being the number of cores.

Is there an efficient way to get the global position of the minimum and value ?

Thanks a lot, 
Best, 
Sam

Comment: Before you resort to MPI, just check the speed of `MINLOC(long_array, 1)`.

Comment: Indeed it is the speed bottleneck of that part of the code. The code works well with MINLOC but spends an unreasonable amount of time there.

Comment: Normally, one uses the MPI call for distributed arrays and the local ones for local arrays. There is rarely any need to consider which one should be used. Do you actually scatter the array and then call the minloc just to get a minimum of a local array? Because one normally does not MPI-parallelize a small part of a program. Either the whole thing is distributed or not.

Comment: Also, if you need a minimum too often, start asking, whether you are using the right algorithm and whether your arrays should not be sorted in the first place.

Comment: Yes, we tested that. We scattered the array, then did MINLOC locally on each and then  find the global minimum value across  all ranks. This works but I was wondering if there was an optimize build in way to do this ?

Comment: You didn't actually answer the question I had: is there a speed difference between `MINLOC(long_array(:), 1)` and `MINLOC(long_array, 1)` ?